# No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view

Tags: android

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
    at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.makeInternal(Snackbar.java:198)
    at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:157)


ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(final ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    final Intent data = result.getData();
                    Snackbar.make(MainFragment.this.binding.getRoot(), data.getStringExtra("nextEvent"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

I know you think "not again..." But why do I get this problem neither in the emulator nor on my samsung devices. This ERROR happens only on one XIAOMI with MIUI 12 (Android 10).

My target SDK is 26.

Anyone faced something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could figure it out...

"Don't keep activities" was enabled in the developer settings.

Maybe the deprecated startActivityForResult will work with this setting enabled.

Comment: Wouldn't think so under all the `registerForActivityResult` gumph it still calls `ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, requestCode, optionsBundle)` in the end - you just have a wrapper api with some contract .. if it does work I'd be surprised.